# Remove function not working properly

Tags: c++, linear-search

My remove function is acting up. Lets say if I add "Apple", "Boy", "Cat" into my array. It sorts it alphabetically. When I remove something, lets say "Boy", it removes it fine. But if I enter in "Brown" it removes "Cat" from my list. It will always remove the one below it alphabetically if it does not find it in the list. If I have those strings I stated above and I enter in "Dog", nothing happens because "Cat" is before "Dog". Any ideas?

```
void StringList::remove(string s)
{
    int loc = search(s, 0, numberOfStrings);
    if(loc!=-1)
    {
        for(int i=loc; i<(numberOfStrings)-1; i++)
        {
            str[i] = str[i+1];
        }
        numberOfStrings--;      
    }
}


int StringList::search(string s, int start, int end)
{
    for(int i=start; i<=end; i++)
    {
        if(str[i]>=s)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You mean, it removes the one that is alphabetically *next* if it cannot find the exact word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of problems I see:

In `StringList::search`, the line

```
if (str[i] >= s)
```

should be changed to

```
if (str[i] == s)
```

You want to find an exact match, not the first lexicographically "greater" string, correct?

Next, the first line in `StringList::remove` should use

```
numberOfStrings - 1
```

instead of just

```
numberOfStrings
```

If `numberOfStrings = 3`, then you want to search in indices `0, 1, 2`, not `0, 1, 2, 3`.

However, instead of changing the parameter in the first line, you could also change (in the function `StringList::search`) the line

```
for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
```

With these fixes, your algorithm *should* work.

The reason you would try to remove "Brown" and get "Cat" removed is because of the lexicographic "greater than" operation in the searching method. When you gave it "Brown", it would see "Cat" and say, hey! "Cat" > "Brown"! Let's return the index of "Cat"! And then the remove method would, well, remove "Cat"...

Comment: If I adjust str[i]>=s it won't add them alphabetically. I just tried that in my function. I have to use the sequential search to find the insertion point to add the strings to my list in alphabetical order.

Comment: @GiBiT09 Then you should have separate helper functions, to use when inserting, as opposed to removing, an item. You need to change that line when removing an item; otherwise you will have the problem I described at the bottom.